# I am creating a collectionview where the heights of all the cells are random. How can I make the vertical spacing in between cells be 0?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in my subclassed UICollectionViewController, I am setting the heights of the cells with this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let cellHeight = arc4random_uniform(100) + 200
    print("cell height: \(cellHeight)")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width/2 - 1, height: CGFloat(cellHeight))
  }
```

And the cells now look like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can make the CollectionViewCells have 0 vertical space in between cells? Obviously this would mean the rows are not aligned, so does that make it impossible to do with a `Flow` layout?

Comment: I think this is good for you https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285258/collectionview-dynamic-cell-height-swift

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did both of these but with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` delegate methods, but they do not eliiminate the verical spacing between some of the cells