# Dynamic cell height programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, frame

Is it possible to make a dynamic cell height programmatically and only using a frames?
Without constraints, autolayout and external libraries!

In this custom tableView cell, i set frame for label with calculating height for text label:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    makeLayout()
}

func makeLayout() {
    let sizeLabel = descriptionLabel.sizeThatFits(bounds.size)
    descriptionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: sizeLabel.height)
}
```

I have view controller with tableView, where i implement his delegate with return automaticDimension, but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CollectionView Dynamic cell height swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285258/collectionview-dynamic-cell-height-swift)

Comment: no, i set frame a label in custom cell, and implement tableView delegate

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You will have to return the height programmatically by implementing the 
[UITableViewDelegate function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

Comment: yeah, but I have a custom cell with a label and set this label with a frame

Comment: Calculate the frame of the UILabel and return the height along with whatever padding you might need. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128797/calculating-uilabel-text-size